# jquery mobile grid issue

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Hello i'm trying to creat an app with jquery mobile but for some reason the grid is not working as intended. The last element is lower than the other ones. Doesn't matter if i use 2-3-4 blocks still last element is lower. Here is my code and fiddle
**html**

```
<fieldset class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="button" value="Hmm"></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="reset" value="No"></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><input type="submit" value="Yes"></div>
</fieldset>
```

**fiddle**
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cp0fc4w/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spaces between the code is converted into `&nbsp;` characters. Remove the spaces within the code and the last element will be aligned correctly.

[**Updated JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8cp0fc4w/2/)

---

Check more about this error: **[How do I remove invisible “  ” which has been automatically added to code in JQM?](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-do-i-remove-invisible-%E2%80%9C-nbsp-nbsp-%E2%80%9D-which-has-been-automatically-added-to-code-in-jqm)**

So the suggested fix is to copy paste the code from browser's `View source` rather than formatted page which has unicode characters appended.